# Application ID issues when using Azure Database Migration Services

Tags: database, azure, azure-migrate

When configuring a new migration tasks I am asked for the application ID and the key. I created the app id and copied the key from the created  account id under the target details. When I save it I get the following error:

```
Unhandled scenario exception. Scenario 'ConnectToTarget.AzureSqlDbMI.Sync.LRS', TaskId '1fa8b4eb-5a2f-4450-adb6-c1a96504f985'.
One or more errors occurred.
Failed to collect data for Azure Resource '/subscriptions/my subscription/resourceGroups/target resource group/providers/Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/managed-instance' using application ID 'adminsql'.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I suspect I configured the application ID incorrectly for the migration service but I don't know where to start fixing it

Comment: It would be difficult to troubleshoot this issue without an exception message or stack trace.
Could you please write to us at DMSfeedback@microsoft.com 
Mention your Azure subscription ID and specific migration scenario you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

dont know if this is the problem your having, but i got the exact same error when i put the ID of the secret, not the ID of the App into the migration tool... I realized i put in the wrong ID and it works now...